# Matplotlib: How to plot heatmap based on values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I need to plot a heatmap based on values in a file. The structure of the file is as follows:

```
,  c1 ,  c2  , ... , cN
-- --    --          --
c1, 1 , 0.24 , ... , 0.37
c2,0.29,  1  , ... , 0.31
...
...
...
cN,0.42, 0.27, ... ,  1
```

I need the output in the form of a heatmap where the labels along both the x-axis and the y-axis are `c1,c2,...,cN`.

These values are not correlation values, but rather the intersection values in the range of 0 to 1. Hence, I am unable to use the `corr()` method. The examples I have seen online usually deal with heat maps of the correlation matrix, or the file is structured in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt with some fake data and assuming that value in each cell can be used as is and does not require more processing.

```py
import seaborn as sns
```

Create fake data

```py
data = """
,  c1 ,  c2  , cN
-- --    --    --
c1, 1 , 0.24 , 0.37
c2,0.29,  1  , 0.31
cN,0.42, 0.27, 1
"""
with open("temp.txt", "wt") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Use pandas to read data in and excluding the line with '--' in it.

```py
data = pd.read_csv("temp.txt",index_col=0, skiprows=[2])
```

Use `seaborn.heatmap` to create a heat map with proper labels.

```
sns.heatmap(data)
```

I get the following output.

[image: Heatmap from matrix csv]

Hope this is what you have in mind.